# Focus edit-form popup for Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, popup, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How can you focus the edit-form Popup for Telerik MVC grid? Solutions that not hack Telerik code are preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [OnEdit](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnEdit) event of the grid, find some input element from the form and focus it. Here is some sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Grid_onEdit(e) {
    var form = e.form;
    $(form).find("input:first").focus();
}
</script>
```